# Шара nas4free монтируется только на чтение

Tags: linux, mount

Довольно давно (несколько лет уже) при загрузке ОС (Fedora) автоматически выполнялось монтирование шары на сервере nas4free. Для этого в файле */etc/fstab* имеется следующая строка:

```
# nas4free
//192.168.0.168/common1 /mnt/nas4free  cifs auto,credentials=/etc/winpassword,gid=users,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

После очередного обновления ОС (до версии Fedora-33) почему-то пропала возможность записи в шару:

```
$ cp proj06.py /mnt/nas4free/Album/
cp: невозможно создать обычный файл '/mnt/nas4free/Album/proj06.py': Отказано в доступе
```

И права доступа при этом, соответствующие:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/nas4free/
итого 6144
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root users       0 янв  1 15:41  Album
```

Т.е. нет у меня прав на запись почему-то. Но, при этом сама ФС смонтирована, вроде бы, с правами на запись:

```
$ mount | grep /mnt/nas4free
//192.168.0.168/common1 on /mnt/nas4free type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.1,cache=strict,username=lary,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=100,forcegid,addr=192.168.0.168,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

Что же произошло?

Comment: Странно, я в этом mount наоборот вижу полное отсутствие прав на запись (uid, gid, file_mode, dir_mode)

Comment: нуда, думаю, `file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775` в опции монтирования спасут отца русской демократии...

Comment: @Fat-Zer - "спасут отца русской демократии... "
- Увы... :-( Я вот чего не понимаю: Ранее, при монтировании шары, я использовал следующий механизм. На сервере у меня была группа *users* у которой были полные права на всю деревяшку шары. В команде монтирования я использовал параметр *gid=users* и всё прекрасно работало. Сейчас почему-то работать перестало! Да что случилось то?!

Comment: @Fat-Zer И что я вижу с хоста на смонтированной шаре - все (!) каталоги имеют права доступа 0777, за исключением тольео одного - каталога шары в папке монтирования - 0775.  Отсюда я делаю вывод, что я перестал быть членом группы users на сервере и оказался в "остальных". Поэтому смотреть могу, а писать - нет.

Answer (score 0):

На сервере у меня есть группа *users* у которой были полные права на всю деревяшку шары. В команде монтирования я использовал параметр *gid=users* и всё прекрасно работало. Я заподозрил, что что-то произошло с группой *users* на моём локальном компе. Смотрим:

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep users
users:x:100:
```

Опа.... Но меня нет в этой группе!
Проверяю другим методом:

```
$ groups
lary wheel
```

Точно - нет!
Ну что-ж, добавлю себя в эту группу:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G users lary
$ groups
lary wheel
```

Неужели не сработало?! А что в файле груп?

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep users
users:x:100:lary
```

А там я присутствую. Это что за мистика?!
Ладно, попробуем перезагрузиться...
Всё в порядке:

```
$ groups
lary wheel users
```

А что с правами на запись?

```
$ cp users.txt /mnt/nas4free/
$
```

Ура - запись прошла без проблем!

Так что мой вывод - при обновлении релиза fedora 32->33 меня удалили из группы *users*. Это привело к тому, что я потерял права на запись на шаре.

Зачем так сделали дистрибьюторы - остаётся только догадываться.

Comment: [Это что за мистика?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11573/110559)